# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] CGI, python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, cgi, simplehttpserver

I've been searching for a solution to this but none helped me.

Key points:

OS: **Ubuntu 18.04**
File to run: **/var/www/html/cgi_test/cgi-bin/hello.py** (exists for sure)
which python3: **/usr/bin/python3** (OS default)
Permissions for files/dirs inside folder cgi_test:

> drwxrwxr-x 1 cgi-bin
>   -rwxrwxrwx 1 cgi-bin/hello.py

Contents of /var/www/html/cgi_test/cgi-bin/hello.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import cgi
import cgitb; cgitb.enable()
print("Content-Type: text/plain\r\n\r\n")
print('hi')
```

Runing command inside folder cgi_test: **python3 -m http.server --cgi --bind 192.168.50.4 8000**
Error/Response when accessing in the browser to http://192.168.50.4:8000/cgi-bin/hello.py:

```
Serving HTTP on 192.168.50.4 port 8000 (http://192.168.50.4:8000/) ...
192.168.50.1 - - [15/Mar/2019 08:14:26] "GET /cgi-bin/hello.py HTTP/1.1" 200 -
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('192.168.50.1', 52548)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/server.py", line 1126, in run_cgi
    os.execve(scriptfile, args, env)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/www/html/cgi_test/cgi-bin/hello.py'
----------------------------------------
192.168.50.1 - - [15/Mar/2019 08:14:26] CGI script exit status 0x7f00
```

And a blank page in the browser.

No more ideas to make this work.

Comment: @Justice_Lords Thanks, I wrote the file in vi, no strange chars there

Answer (score 0):

Might be a bit late, but I had a similar issue which I fixed by having the correct python version in the first line of the cgi (.py) script. Eg. `#!/usr/bin/python3.7`

Comment: A more general answer/addition to your answer: The shebang must specify a program that really exists. I had a similiar problem that on Ubuntu20.04 I wrote `#!/usr/bin/bash` and on Ubuntu14.04 it failed with the forementioned error "FileNotFound" because under that location is no bash executable

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, because I copied a .py file directly from Windows.
So I tried to delete and code again on Linux, finally fixed it.
Maybe they have different encoding styles.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).